# Enzyme shallow render is rendering children components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, npm, enzyme

I'm trying to shallow render a component to perform some basic unit tests.

The component I am doing this on has two child components which are rendered several times each depending on the parents props.

When querying the shallow rendered component, the child elements are being rendered -fully- also, meaning that the children's HTML elements are also accessible.

I am using Karma, Browserify, Jasmine and Enzyme, and can post the configs for each if needed. Has anybody seen similar behaviour before?

Comment: This is expected, it will render anything in the component.

Comment: @zackify Sorry, i'll edit the OP, what I meant is that it seems to be rendering the child components fully, aka, the childrens HTML. My understanding is that the shallow render should only go one layer deep.

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct behaviour. The different to the other render methods from enzyme is, that it does not call any lifecycle methods and that it does not convert to real html, but it will render all its childs and childs of the childs and so on.

Comment: Are there options that *don't* render child components at all? I'm running into weird dependency issues and was hoping not to have to mock all the child components individually.