# Enzyme's shallow is rendering children's children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to set up some simple testing in Jest and Enzyme for my React App. I'm using `shallow` to render the main container for my app , however it appears that the children and all of the children below are being rendered.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined

       7 | export function getRandomColor() {
       8 |      console.log(colors);
    >  9 |      return colorsKeys[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsLength)];
         |                       ^
      10 | }
      11 |
      12 | export function determineColor(genotype) {

      at getRandomColor (src/utils/determineColor.js:9:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/exampleState.js:10:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/reducers/flowersReducer.js:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/reducers/indexReducer.js:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.js:14:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/utils/determineColor.js:5:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/NewFlowerFromPunnettButton.js:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Dashboard.js:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.jsx:6:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/App.test.js:4:1)
```

Per the [Enzyme docs](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) "Shallow rendering is useful to constrain yourself to testing a component as a unit, and to ensure that your tests aren't indirectly asserting on behavior of child components."

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725254/enzyme-shallow-render-is-rendering-children-components) seems to clarify that `shallow` "will render all its childs and childs of the childs and so on."

```
    //App.test.js
    import React from "react";
    // shallow prevents rendering of sub components????
    import { shallow, mount, render } from "enzyme";
    import App from "../src/App";

    describe("<App />", () => {
        const app = shallow(<App />);
        it("Should render ", () => {
            expect(app).toMatchSnapShot();
        });
        it("Should have <Punnett/> <Dashboard/> and <FlowerTable />", () => {
            expect(app.find("<Punnett />")).toBeTruthy();
            expect(app.find("<Dashboard/>")).toBeTruthy();
            expect(app.find("<FlowerTable />")).toBeTruthy();
        });

    });
```

```
    //App.jsx
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

    import "./css/App.css";
    import Punnett from "./components/Punnett";
    import FlowerTable from "./components/FlowerTable/FlowerTable";
    import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";

    class App extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <Fragment>
                    <div className="App">
                        <Punnett />
                        <Dashboard />
                    </div>
                    <div className="App">
                        <FlowerTable display={true} />
                    </div>
                </Fragment>
            );
        }
    }

    export default App;
```

```
    // determineColor.js
    import { colors } from "../types/colors";
    const colorsKeys = Object.keys(colors);
    const colorsLength = colorsKeys.length;

    import { store } from "../index";

    export function getRandomColor() {
        console.log(colors);
        return colorsKeys[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsLength)];
    }
```

I'm expecting that either shallow does not render the children, or if the intended behavior is to render all children, that the children be able to import their modules correctly. Swapping `shallow` for `render` results in the same error.

Reproducible by cloning and running `npm run test` on https://github.com/nodes777/flower-game-phaser3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shallow` does render children only, you are correct. root cause: seems `"./components/Dashboard";`  has code inside that runs on `import` - some top level code that is execution not declaration.

You may either change `Dashboard` not doing that, or provide data it needs to work, or mock it explicitly in every single test that may import it directly or indirectly:

App.test.js:

```
jest.mock('./components/Dashboard');
```

if you choose later approach you may consider automocking by creating `components/Dashboard/__mocks__/index.jsx`(or how is name of file with Dashboard) but beware of [bug in jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2070) that disallow you from using automock for more than one `index.js` regardless they are in different folders

Comment: You're right, had some unnecessary code in "./components/Dashboard" that ran on import. Deleted it and now I have a new bug. Progress! Thank you!